# File read fails when using Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, delayed-job

How to check that my params['Filedata'] is corrupted or not?

I have function it's reading file from `params['Filedata']` and writing it to the other file.

```
File.open(upload_file, "wb") { |f| f.write(params['Filedata'].read) }
```

this line working fine for me..

But when i am calling this function with delayed job function `send_later` than I am getting error with `params['Filedata'].read`.

Comment: What do you mean corrupted? Edit the question to show us the code in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing `params['Filedata']` refers to a uploaded file.

Rails handles uploaded data as temporary files, which are deleted after the request is completed. If you want to access the file later, you need to copy it to a more permanent location.